# sscanf cannot read after a VideoWriter initialization

Tags: c++, opencv, scanf

I am using a sscanf to read data from a file through a buffer, everything worked fine until I added this line :

```
VideoWriter video("test0001.avi",CV_FOURCC('H','2','6','4'),30.0,c,true);
```

if I comment the line above ,the sscanf get the correct result, however, if I use my videoWriter (namespace cv) the sscanf doesn't seem to be able to read the line.
I am using this code to read :

```
cout << test.LineBuffer << endl;
if ( (sscanf(test.LineBuffer, "%*f {\"x\":%f,\"y\":%f,\"o\":%f}", &xi, &yi, &oi )) != 3 )
    {
        cout <<"read " <<  sscanf(test.LineBuffer, "%*f {\"x\":%f,\"y\":%f,\"o\":%f}", &xi, &yi, &oi ) << " numbers \n " <<endl;
        fprintf(stderr,"error ");
        return -1;
    }
```

I get this result :

```
1440074599.111 {"x":1.538,"y":2.095,"o":-0.699}
read 0 numbers
```

we can see test.Linebuffer contain the expected value. but sscanf won't read it if I initialized my VideoWriter before, even if it completly unconnected tothe other variables

Comment: Could it be a locale problem? Are you on a system with a language that uses a comma for decimal seperator?

Comment: i'm on fedora. the weird thing is that if I comment the line above,the sscanf works perfetly fine.